# java code for reading text

Tags: java

i need a sample code for this

if text file is not empty then string s = first line of text of the text file.

please help me out.

ok not a homework question i am not looking for the solution just point me to the correct reference material.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @rover12 - I'll take your "this is not homework" assertion at face value.  But based on your other questions, it looks like you are trying to learn how to program in Java by asking questions on SO.  I suggest that you go to your local bookshop (or Amazon.com), leaf through the "Learn to program in Java" texts, and buy one.  Or do one of the online Java tutorials.

Comment: @rover12 - also when you DO have questions to ask (that you couldn't find answers to in your textbook / tutorial) ... take the time to write your questions clearly, in detail, with decent formatting, and proper grammar, spelling and PUNCTUATION.  If you want people to spend time answering, you should spend time asking questions properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like homework, do the following and ask about specific problems.

1. Open the file using FileReader, and wrap that in a BufferedReader
2. Call ReadLine on the BufferedReader, set the return value to your string.
3. if any of the above throws an exception, catch it and set your string to ""

Answer (score 0):

Some hints (because this smells homework and I'm not going to do it for you): decorate a [`FileReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) with a [`BufferedReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and check [`BufferedReader#readLine()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

The sun java tutorials have examples and explanations for tasks like this.

The [IO Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/)  has a section in the File I/O section  called Reading, Writing and Creating Files which looks like what you are looking for